# Questions subtracting One from a Vector R

Tags: r, vector, subset

I'm sure this question has been asked but I couldn't find a direct answer.  This should be so easy, however, I'm struggling to find an answer.  Basically I have a df which has 10 columns/vectors.  There is one Vector that I want to subset and then reduce by one.  Below is my code.  I'm sure it would work but I'm thinking there must be an easier way. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
diffuse_objects <- c("Diffuse Nebula", "Elliptical Galaxy", "Spiral Galaxy",      "Galaxy", "Planetary Nebula",
                 "Nebula", "Cluster Nebulosity")



#subset diffuse Ojbects
newdf2 <- newdf[newdf$Type == diffuse_objects,] 
#Change from character to Numeric
newdf2$Magnitude <- as.numeric(newdf2$Magnitude)
#Subtract -1 
newdf3 <- newdf2[, "Magnitude"] - 1
newdf4 <-cbind(newdf3, newdf2)
```

Comment: `==` should be `%in%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
diffuse_objects <- c("Diffuse Nebula", "Elliptical Galaxy", "Spiral Galaxy",      "Galaxy", "Planetary Nebula",
                 "Nebula", "Cluster Nebulosity")



#subset diffuse Ojbects
newdf2 <-filter(newdf,Type %in% diffuse_objects)
#Change from character to Numeric
newdf2$Magnitude <- as.numeric(newdf2$Magnitude)-1
```

Comment: Would you show me a way to use sapply to subtract the diffuse_ojbects over the original df?   Save me time trying to bind it back.  Cleaner as well.